# estimate the average speed

Tags: calculus

the parametric equation of `x=t*cos(t), y=t*sin(t)`

By calculating the position at `t = 2.5 and t=2.51, estimate the speed at t=2.5.`

Comment: Do you know how slope is defined?

Comment: Have you calculated the two positions $(x(2.5).y(2.5))$ and $(x(2.51), y(2.51))$ like the problem asks you to? That part is just calculator work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(t) = t(\cos t, \sin t)$, then the velocity at $t=2.5$ is approximated by $p'(2.5) \approx \frac{1}{2.51-2.5}(p(2.51)-p(2.5))$, and the corresponding speed by $\|\frac{1}{2.51-2.5}(p(2.51)-p(2.5))\|$.

Substituting numbers: $p'(2.5) \approx (-2.2932,  -1.4199)$, and $\|p'(2.5) \|\approx 2.6972$.

Using derivatives, we have $p'(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)+t(-\sin t, \cos t)$, which
gives $p'(2.5) \approx ( -2.2973,  -1.4044)$ and $\|p'(2.5)\| \approx 2.6926$, so the finite difference approximation is fairly close.

Comment: so I know how to do the derivative method. I am confused what you mean by p(t)

Comment: $p(t)$ is just shorthand for the pair $(x(t),y(t))$, where $x,y$ are as you have above in the question. If you use derivatives, you need to differentiate $x,y$ with respect to $t$, so you get the pair $(\cos t -t \sin t, \sin t + t \cos t)$.

Comment: solid, thanks a bunch.